# Understanding scope in a Java inner class

Tags: java, android, scope, inner-classes

In an Android project, I am using the code below. I get the error: `variable tts might not have been initialized`. If I change the place where the variable tts is declared, I no longer get the error. If I comment out the two lines which reference tts in the inner OnInitListener class, I also no longer get the error (but nothing interesting happens either).

So, I deduce that the inner class cannot "see" the `tts` variable if it is declared in the enclosing method (even when it is declared as `final`), but it can see it when it is declared as a instance variable of the enclosing class.

I come from a JavaScript background; obviously Java treats variable scope in a different way in this context. I would be grateful if you could explain what Java is doing under the hood, so that I can make sense of these differences.

```
package com.example.texttospeech;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    //private TextToSpeech tts; // UNCOMMENT THIS...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        testTextToSpeech();
    }

    private void testTextToSpeech() {
        final String toSpeak = getString(R.string.hello_world);
        final int mode = TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH;
        final HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        final TextToSpeech tts; // ... AND COMMENT THIS OUT...

        tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),
                new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int status) {
                        if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                            // ... OR SIMPLY COMMENT OUT THE NEXT TWO LINES
                            tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                            tts.speak(toSpeak, mode, hashMap);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-#1 all final variables in the method are implicitly copied as fields of your onInitClass.  It also has an implicit field to your outer class.  All of this can be a source of unintended memory leaks, and by leak we mean unintended creating a reference that prevents the garbage collector from doing its job, so care is required in what you declare final.

-#2 The reason it is saying tts might not have been initialized is because you use it before assigning it a value.  Final makes the reference immutable, so you can only assign a value to final when it's declared.  If you don't assign a value, that means what's occupying the memory space could very well be random garbage from the last time that memory space was used to store a value.  You can explicitly set tts = null, but a final variable set to null is utterly useless (it can't be changed), so you'll need to set its actual value in the same line you declare it.

E.g. final TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), listener);

-#3 Your inner class can reference variables in the outer class.  All you do is write OuterClass.this.myfield;

So this might be a viable way to re-write your code.

```
TextToSpeech tts;  //class field

private void testTextToSpeech() {
        final String toSpeak = getString(R.string.hello_world);
        final int mode = TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH;
        final HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {

                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                        tts.speak(toSpeak, mode, hashMap);
                    }
                }
            }); 
}
```

Comment: Where is can I learn about what implicit fields are created and when? #2 seems to create a chicken-and-egg situation where `listener` cannot be created until `tts` has been initialized. As for #3, I can see that the inner class can access the variable from the outer class when it is declared as `private TextToSpeech tts;` in the outer class.

Comment: Honestly, I learned here on stackoverflow reading questions and answers :)  There's not much to learn, it's just inner classes have a reference to the outter class, as well as all the final fields in the method it was declared in.  So as long as the inner class lives, those other objects can't be collected by the GC.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your viable method is the same as what I achieved through the "uncomment/comment out" changes that I alluded to in my sample code? It seems to me that the issue comes from the fact that Java compiler insists on `tts` being set as `final` if it is declared inside `testTextToSpeech()`. Even if I use `final TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(...);` the compiler is still unhappy.  By the time the `onInit()` method is called, `tts` will point to an initialized object, but the compiler can't see that far ahead. All it sees is `final`. Is that an accurate understanding?

Comment: Yeah it is the same actually..., what was not working for you putting it as a class field?  As for declaring tts in the method, yeah it's a catch-22 because tts must be final/constant, but as a class field, it isn't required to be for the inner class to reference it.  The reason it's required to be constant is that if it wasn't, it would arguably create ambiguity which value the inner class would be using.

Comment: I have no problem about putting it in as a class field. I was just wanting to understand why it has to be a class field. Now I understand that the compiler is concerned about potential ambiguity, and that a class field removes that concern. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` instance gets passed the reference to `tts` to it's implicit constructor, but - at this point - `tts` has not been initialized, but only declared (and you cannot pass an uninitialized variable (which a local variable that lives on the stack will always be) to any method since it does not have a value). You assign a newly created object of type `TextToSpeech` to the variable `tts` which depends on an instance of `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` (constructor) which depends `tts` -> cyclic dependency.

By declaring `tts` as a member variable, it will automatically be initialized with `null`. And since `tts` is a member variable, the `TextToSpeech.OnInitListener` instance will always be able to access the current value of `tts` as it gets passed an implicit reference to the outer instance of `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's enough to write this code in a slightly different way to see what's going on here.

```
final TextToSpeech tts;

TextToSpeech.OnInitListener listener = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
  @Override
  public void onInit(int status) {
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
    tts.speak(toSpeak, mode, hashMap);
  }
}

tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), listener);
```

Basically, in the moment the `listener` is instantiated `tts` is declared, but it still does not exist. This is what the warning is about. The compiler does not look ahead and if you make `tts` a class variable then for all it knows, your program may try to use the `listener` before `tts` is instantiated. By putting the `tts` declaration in the same local scope you avoid that risk.

---

So what I would suggest to do is to make `testTextToSpeech` return a reference to `tts`:

```
private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tts = testTextToSpeech();
}

private TextToSpeech testTextToSpeech() {
    final String toSpeak = getString(R.string.hello_world);
    final int mode = TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH;
    final HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    final TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                        tts.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                        tts.speak(toSpeak, mode, hashMap);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    return tts;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is clear, but your suggested modifications to the code do not solve the issue. `tts` is still not initialized when `listener` is created.

Comment: It was not a suggested modification. It was just my try on showing what's going on. As for the suggested modification... [editing the answer] maybe something like that. It's not the most beautiful code in the world, but it should work.

Comment: I see how this works. However, if I declare `private TextToSpeech tts;` as an instance variable, then I don't need to create a separate private variable inside the `testTextToSpeech()` method. And `testTextToSpeech()` would need to declare that it returns a TextToSpeech object, or else the script won't compile.